# I want to show checkboxes for selected tree nodes only but I am getting radiobuttons for every element in the tree

Tags: java, tree, xul, zk

Here is my code

```
<?page title="MVVM Tree POC"?>
<zk>
    <borderlayout height="800px">
        <west size="25%"></west>
        <center>
            <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
                viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.nagarro.controller.TreeController')"
                title="Dynamic Tree" border="normal">
                <tree multiple="true" checkmark="true" rows="5"
                    model="@bind(vm.employeeTreeModel)">
                    <treecols>
                        <treecol label="First Name" align="center" />
                        <treecol label="Last Name" align="center" />
                        <treecol label="Age" align="center" />
                        <treecol label="Index" align="center" />
                    </treecols>
                    <template name="model" var="node" status="s">
                        <treeitem checkable="true">
                            <treerow style="text-align:center;">
                                <treecell
                                    label="@bind(node.data.firstName)" style="text-align:left;" />
                                <treecell
                                    label="@bind(node.data.lastName)" />
                                <treecell label="@bind(node.data.age)" />
                                <treecell label="@bind(s.index)" />
                            </treerow>

                        </treeitem>
                    </template>
                </tree>

            </window>
        </center>
    </borderlayout>
</zk>
```

I checked the zkoss [reference](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Tree) for the multiple selection property and made the necessary changes in the above zul file. Still it doesnt show checkboxes. Instead it shows only radiobuttons.

**Also, I want to show checkboxes in front of some selected tree nodes and not all of them.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
setMultiple(true)
```

on the model instance returned by `vm.employeeTreeModel` not the tree it self.

If you want just some to be checkable, change this

```
<treeitem checkable="true">
```

to something like that

```
<treeitem checkable="@load(node.checkable)">
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Nabil A. answer, I found out that if you're using TreeitemRenderer, you need to set multiples like this:

```
public class MyItemRenderer implements TreeitemRenderer<DefaultTreeNode<MyObj>> {
    public void render(final Treeitem item, DefaultTreeNode<MyObj> data, int index) {
        data.getModel().setMultiple(true);
        //rest of the code...
    }
}
```